# Accessing vector in vector class returning error conversion from 'Test1::Test2' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<Test1::Test2>' requested

Tags: vector

I  am having issue in below code sample where accessing vector v1 from another vector test2DBVector type Test2, returning non-scalar error. Seems like I am not writing the syntax in range for loop correctly.
If someone could help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

class Test1
{ 
  public:
    string s1;

    class Test2{
    public:
    vector<string> v1;
    };

    vector<Test2> test2DBVector;

    void updateTest2DBVector()
    {

      s1 = "Hello World";
      Test2 t2Obj;
      t2Obj.v1.push_back(s1);
      test2DBVector.push_back(t2Obj);

   }  

 };//endofClass Test1


 int main()
 {
   Test1 t1Obj;

   t1Obj.updateTest2DBVector();

   for(vector<Test1::Test2> tempObj:t1Obj.test2DBVector)
   {

    for(vector<string> tempString:tempObj.v1)
    {

         cout<<tempString;
    }  

  }

  return 0; 
 
 }//endOfMain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Test1 t1Obj;

t1Obj.updateTest2DBVector();
/*
     test2DBVector returns the test2 type, so that's why used Test1::Test2 in 
     for range loop which will define the type of obj, which is test2 type.
     obj.v1 returns the string type, thats why used string type in for range  
     loop to receive that.

*/

for(Test1::Test2 obj:t1Obj.test2DBVector)
{
    for(string s:obj.v1)
    {
        cout<<s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: vector, vector<Test2> test2DBVector , type is Test2 and will return Test2 object, that's why outer for loop is (Test1::Test2 obj:t1Obj.test2DBVEctor) , here obj is Test2 type. Then Test2 object obj access to v1 obj.v1, which will return string type. that's why inner for loop is (string s:obj.v1). I hope it will help.

Comment: Please add all explanation **to your answer** by editing it, not to the comment secion